# how to access all the documents of a collection with some condition from realtime database firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. [This is my Realtime database structure] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGWgt.png)
2. [Full structure] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRjHf.png)
3. [Full structure] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy4oq.png)

- In 'collection' I want to get all the id's which are having 'AC complaint' and status as 'waiting' in it.
- like I want the output like for example:
- A2QMPPbXUxVjeyCBK6AVVmrTcw12
  BQ8BqdOrbKZuJnSOTAEoCtfgxjl1
- this is user ids in complaints which has it's 'AC complaint' status as 'waiting'. Also, that it is  not necessary that every id has 'AC complaint'.

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: DatabaseReference  ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('complaints');
DataSnapshot snapshot = await ref.get();
print(snapshot.value!);

by this i got my full database in format <Map<Object?,Object?> 
but when i try to type cast it into Map<String,dynamic> which i want it shows error that Map<Object?,Object?> is not a subtype of Map<String,dynamic>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  Please also respond using @AlexMamo